# how to create image and header it in PHP?

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have one problem with PHP create image. What is wrong with my following code?

```
<?php
$filename = 'play';
$img = "http://www.slcentral.com/ipod-mp3-player/5.JPG";


$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
$cleft = 0;
$ctop = 45;
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(480, 270);
imagecopy($canvas, $image, 0, 0, $cleft, $ctop, 480, 360);
$image = $canvas;

$imageWidth = imagesx($image);
$imageHeight = imagesy($image);

// ADD THE PLAY ICON
$play_icon = "f-play.png";
$logoImage = imagecreatefrompng($play_icon);
imagealphablending($logoImage, TRUE);
$logoWidth = imagesx($logoImage);
$logoHeight = imagesy($logoImage);

// CENTER PLAY ICON
$left = round($imageWidth / 2) - round($logoWidth / 2);
$top = round($imageHeight / 2) - round($logoHeight / 2);

// CONVERT TO PNG SO WE CAN GET THAT PLAY BUTTON ON THERE
imagecopy( $image, $logoImage, $left, $top, 0, 0, $logoWidth, $logoHeight);
imagepng( $image, $filename .".png", 9);
// MASHUP FINAL IMAGE AS A JPEG
$input = imagecreatefrompng($filename .".png");
$output = imagecreatetruecolor($imageWidth, $imageHeight);
$white = imagecolorallocate($output, 255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($output, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $white);
imagecopy($output, $input, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);

// OUTPUT TO 'i' FOLDER
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($output, $filename . ".jpg", 95);
// UNLINK PNG VERSION
@unlink($filename .".png");
die();
?>
```

Above code is create one image from giving url and add play icon to it. And I want to access to http://coolrss.com/create-img.php it will show image with play icon.

Please help!

Comment: and what is your problem? any error shown in log?

Comment: Plz click this http://coolrss.com/create-img.php you will see error

Comment: do you want to spam? get traffic in your own web? include your error in question

Comment: No, I want to add play icon in my image to show in my website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make sure the path has the right permission or you will get:

  `PHP Warning: imagepng(): Unable to open 'play.png' for writing: Permission denied in /var/www/coolrss/public_html/create-img.php on line 32`
- Make sure you have installed GD.
- Start your code with this header (after the php tag (`<?php`))

  `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");`
- At the end (last line) add

  `imagejpeg($output, NULL, 100);`

Your code looks like this now:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$filename = 'play';
$img = "http://www.slcentral.com/ipod-mp3-player/5.JPG";


$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
$cleft = 0;
$ctop = 45;
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(480, 270);
imagecopy($canvas, $image, 0, 0, $cleft, $ctop, 480, 360);
$image = $canvas;

$imageWidth = imagesx($image);
$imageHeight = imagesy($image);

// ADD THE PLAY ICON
$play_icon = "f-play.png";
$logoImage = imagecreatefrompng($play_icon);
imagealphablending($logoImage, TRUE);
$logoWidth = imagesx($logoImage);
$logoHeight = imagesy($logoImage);

// CENTER PLAY ICON
$left = round($imageWidth / 2) - round($logoWidth / 2);
$top = round($imageHeight / 2) - round($logoHeight / 2);

// CONVERT TO PNG SO WE CAN GET THAT PLAY BUTTON ON THERE
imagecopy( $image, $logoImage, $left, $top, 0, 0, $logoWidth, $logoHeight);
imagepng( $image, $filename .".png", 9);
// MASHUP FINAL IMAGE AS A JPEG
$input = imagecreatefrompng($filename .".png");
$output = imagecreatetruecolor($imageWidth, $imageHeight);
$white = imagecolorallocate($output, 255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($output, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $white);
imagecopy($output, $input, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);
imagejpeg($output, NULL, 100);
```

Screenshot  - Works for me

[image]

Comment: I have added header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); before imagejpeg(), but still not work. Or should I put it on the top of code?

Comment: at the end of the file (last line) add: `imagejpeg($output, NULL, 100);`

Comment: after add this, I get white image. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72019/discussion-between-lea-tano-and-richat-chhayvandy).